# Maven run does not include Junit tests

Tags: junit, automated-tests, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin, junit-jupiter

I am trying to run tests by running the maven (pom.xml) file.

All I get is that the tests were not ran:

[image]

the pom includes the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <defaultGoal>test</defaultGoal>
</build>
```

for some reason, it wouldn't pick up the tests:

[image]

```
@Test
public void testMultiply() {
    MathUtils mathUtils = new MathUtils();
        assertEquals(0, mathUtils.add(-1, 1),
                "Add method should return the sum of two numbers");
}
```

I can't find any thing wronge with the pom.xml.
Any suggestion?

project on github: https://github.com/subhisamara/Junit-maven-selenium

Comment: Can you show the imports of your test?

Comment: @johanneslink you may see the whole project on https://github.com/subhisamara/Junit-maven-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Add these plug-ins to your pom.xml file:

```
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <!--
    
    default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging 
    
    -->
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Run by this command: mvn test